# ArrayAccess performance php

Tags: php, oop, spl, arrayaccess

I am currently working on a container for a php project that would seem like a perfect candidate to simplify with the ArrayAccess interface.

I feel like this would be great but the only drawback I see to implementing the interface might be performance.

Is there a significant performance hit when methods are being called from an offsetGet or offsetSet method? Are there any other downsides to using ArrayAccess?

Cheers.

Comment: "Nah". Use [Pimple](https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple/blob/master/src/Pimple/Container.php#L34). It even has an  [implementation](https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple/tree/master/ext/pimple) in C.

Comment: The comment above has no relation to the original _ArrayAccess performance php_ question.